# Stopping Samba Auto-reload on boot

Tags: linux-mint, boot, samba

Trying to boot my Linux 17 mint. It stops at "Stopping Samba Auto-reload integration." It hangs there and will not boot.

I've tried recovery boot however the dpkg manager in the recovery isn't working because the Samba is network related and it won't fetch any of the packages.

I would provide more detail but since it won't boot I don't really know how to provide a stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Have landed up in a similar problem..
Although, I just figured out you can get to the grub screen by

1. holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while boot-process and
2. then press <kbd>C</kbd> to enter the grub command console

I also figured out you can get to the login screen by pressing - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> while boot up!

Comment: OK, nos that I have that open, what do I do?